# Find Control() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created 5 text boxes in a button click event and i have to get the values in the text boxes when the dynamically generated button is clicked.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
   HtmlGenericControl tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
   HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
   HtmlGenericControl tdbtn = new HtmlGenericControl("td");           
   TextBox txt=new TextBox();
   txt.ID="txt_"+i.ToString();
   td.Controls.Add(txt);  
   Button btn=new Button();
   btn.ID="btn_"+i.ToString();
   btn.Click+=new EventHandler(btnpay_Click);
   btn.Text="Pay";    
   tdbtn.Controls.Add(btn);        
   tr.Controls.Add(td);
   tr.Controls.Add(tdbtn);
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tr);
}
```

}

But i couldn't get the Values in the text boxes at **btnpay_Click**

```
protected void btnpay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn = sender as Button;
        string[] splitvaues = btn.ID.Split('_');
        string identity = splitvaues[1];
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt =PlaceHolder1.FindControl("txt_" + identity) as TextBox;

}
```

Can Anybody tell me a way to solve this problem?

Comment: what is plcfee1? You may have to find control in your PlaceHolder1.

Comment: FindControl works searching in the controls collection of the naming container.  
I suppose that `plcfee1` is not the naming container for txt_1

Comment: Its actually PlaceHolder1 not plcfee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code.....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            createcontrol();
        }
    }
private void createcontrol()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            HtmlGenericControl tdbtn = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = "txt_" + i.ToString();
            td.Controls.Add(txt);
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "btn_" + i.ToString();
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnpay_Click);
            btn.Text = "Pay";
            tdbtn.Controls.Add(btn);
            tr.Controls.Add(td);
            tr.Controls.Add(tdbtn);
            plh1.Controls.Add(tr);
        }
    }
protected void btnpay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn = sender as Button;
        string[] splitvaues = btn.ID.Split('_');
        string identity = splitvaues[1].ToString();
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt = plh1.FindControl("txt_" + identity) as TextBox;
        string q = txt.Text;

    }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createcontrol();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) doesn't recurse down the control tree. It only searches the controls directly in the [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.aspx) of the container.

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly
>   contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not
>   search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.

You need to write a recursive FindControl. Something like:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control control, string id)
{
  if (control == null || control.ID == id) return control;

  foreach (var c in control.Controls)
  {
    var found = c.FindControlRecursive(id);
    if (found != null) return found;
  }

  return null;
}
```